# Sails.JS models not globally accessible even though Globals.JS contains models:true

Tags: sails.js

I previously had a Sails project version 0.12.11 & just upgraded to version 1.0.2.

My Globals.JS file looks like this:

```
module.exports.globals = {
    _: require("lodash"),
    async: require("async"),
    sails: true,
    services: true,
    models: true
};
```

However, I defined a User model in my api/models/User.js.

In my controller code, none of my controllers are able to get access to User. I get an error `User is not defined.`

If I add a bunch of `console.log("aaaa")` entries into my User.JS and run the sails server, none of those console logs appear.

Yet, all the files under `api/services/*` have still loaded correctly and I can access those files globally without any issue!

Comment: In config/globals.js, id, do you have `models: true`?

Comment: @streleckify I copy/pasted what I had in globals.js. It is indeed included

Comment: If you haven't already, you may find it beneficial to run through the official upgrade procedures & checks for Sails 1.x [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0)